Create one user with the keyboard/mouse access and other user with no access
I need help creating two users: 'a_user' with autologin enabled, limited permissions, and without keyboard access, and 'tech_user' with keyboard access and root privileges. When the system boots with 'a_user', 'tech_user' should be able to connect a keyboard, log out 'a_user', possibly by pressing a special key, and log in to 'tech_user' using the password.
